# Azure Devops multiple Custom conditions

Tags: azure-devops

I've 2 variables in azure devops

```
Var1= A,B,C
Var2= 1,2
```

I need to run a task with the following conditions

```
Var1=A,B,C & Var2=1,2

Var1=A & Var2=1
```

From the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) i can only able to see more simple custom conditions

like

```
and(succeeded(), in(variables['Var1'], 'A','B','C'))
```

Here how to include the Var2 using the and condition again *more like  multiple custom condition*.

In a simple C# world we will wrote this like below

```
(Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==1 || Var2==2)
```

**Update**

My final conditions looks like this

```
( ((Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==2)) || ((Var1==A) &&(Var2==1)))
```

How could i achieve this in the custom conditions ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Azure Devops multiple Custom conditions

It seems you want use the matrix variable, it is like every variable, you could use it in this way:

```
and(succeeded(), in(variables['Var1'], 'A','B','C'), in(variables['Var2'], '1','2'))
```

Separating variable conditions with commas, and it works fine on my side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I've updated my question with some clear thing, actually with your answer i also want another condition to be combined as `and`, how could i do that ?

Comment: @Jayendran, The condition in your update doesn't make sense. If any condition match the `((Var1==A) &&(Var2==1))`, it must match the `((Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==1 || Var2==2))`, so the conditions in the first half are invalid. If you have more needs, you may need to come up with a reasonable condition so that I will know your needs.

Comment: sorry i messed up with the logic earlier. now I've updated the logic correctly in my update in the question. Can you look into that ? now you can see what i mean by combined multiple conditions with `and` & `or`

Comment: @Jayendran, I think the update logic is still incorrect. The value of **Var2** can only be **one value** at a time, it cannot satisfy conditions `((Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==2))` **AND** `((Var1==A) &&(Var2==1))` at the same time. The result of the condition is always False. Am I right? Based my understanding of your question, we currently cannot seem to achieve the combination of **multiple matrix variables**. In other words, we cannot achieve ((condition A && conditionB) && (condition C)).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, +1 before accepting the answer just one more question,  if i change the *AND* to *OR* then is it possible to achieve ? like this `( ((Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==2)) || ((Var1==A) &&(Var2==1))) ` ?

Comment: @Jayendran, The answer is yes. You could add two same tasks in the pipeline, one with the condition `((Var1==A || Var1==B || Var1==C) && (Var2==2))` and another with condition `((Var1==A) &&(Var2==1))`, this should be work.

Comment: But i would like to implement in the same task. So as per your this logic cannot be implemented in the same task right ?

Comment: @Jayendran, Indeed, you are right! Just like I said before, we currently could not achieve the combination of **multiple matrix** variables.

Answer (score 1):

I've just solved having this issue of requiring multiple conditions to be met by having the variables resolve to a single variable for use in the task condition

```
variables:
  isMaster: $[eq(variables.branchName, 'master')]
  isStaging: $[eq(variables.branchName, 'staging')]
  willDelete: $[and(eq(variables.isMaster, 'false'), eq(variables.isStaging, 'false'))]
```

....

```
  - task: HelmDeploy@0
    displayName: Remove instance
    condition: eq(variables.willDelete,'true')
```

my first attempt at putting it all in the task condition

```
and(not(variables.isMaster, true), not(variables.isStaging, true))
```

failed, and when I looked at the debug I saw it didn't expand it all

```
Evaluating: and(eq(variables['isMaster'], 'true'), eq(variables['isStaging'], 'true'))
Expanded: and(eq('False', 'true'), eq(variables['isStaging'], 'true'))
Result: False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a custom condition for the classic AzureDevops build pipeline requirement: the build should create an artifact if a branch is a master or release/* branch.
**Custom condition is mention below**:
`and(succeeded(),or(eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'), startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/')))`