# Azure devops Pipeline , Condition after PR

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Hello I'm looking for the right condition,
Activate the CI after PR
And specific Job will run only if there was a change in a particular folder I selected.

I do not want them to run after PR if there was no change / update in the particular folder I choose.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-changed-files

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk 
added is work great thx
how can I do 2 condition together , i want to active it only in PR to master

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718013/azure-devops-multiple-custom-conditions

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk
have option to affect the Plugin to work only after PR complete ?
and if run it individual CI is will work without the Plugin?

Comment: yea, put condition in the plugin step

Comment: condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
@ShaykiAbramczyk

to active the plugin just for PR complete, is it right ?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk
If I put a condition on the plugin and it does not go into it, then the conditions that there are from the plugin in other Jobs do not go in at all.
I want the plugin and its terms to work only in Pr.

If someone manually runs the CI it will not affect, that's my goal.